# Intellij IDEA Language injection with Java 21 template expression

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use Intellij IDEA language injection with Java 21 template expressions.

Without adding a variable interpolation it works fine, but by adding some interpolation ( \{someVariable} ) the syntax highlighting disappears.

(the thymeleaf tags is because I'm doing an experiment to convert thymeleaf templates to html string using java 21)

[image]

[image]

I tried adding a custom configuration in the language injection plugin, but I was unsuccessful.

I wanted the html highlighting to be maintained using the Java 21 string template

Comment: Can you share a sample code for the problem, better with a screenshot?